# Issue in cmp statement?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am using NASM. I think there is some issue in my cmp statement, it is simple comparision between first index of array and a key, both are same so it should print Y, but it is printing N. How to fix it?

```
jmp start
array: dw 1,2,3,4,5
key: dw 1
start:

cmp [array],word key
jne not_found
jmp found

found:
mov dx , 'Y';print Y if key is found
jmp end

not_found:
mov dx , 'N';print N if key is not found

end:
mov ah , 2h ;
int 21h ;
mov ah , 0x4c 
int 0x21 ; synonymous to return 0;
```

Comment: You are comparing first element of array with address of `key`.

Comment: How can i compare first element of array with key?

Answer (score 1):

> How can i compare first element of array with key?

```
; put the value of key in the ax register
mov ax,[key]
; compare the first value in array against ax (i.e. the key)
cmp [array],ax
```

---

By the way, instead of

```
mov ah , 0x4c 
int 0x21 ; synonymous to return 0;
```

You can use:

```
int 0x20  ; terminate program with errorlevel=0
```

Comment: Moving value of key to ax is not solving the problem.It is still printing N.

Comment: Works fine for me. I get Y as the output. Did you make sure to change the `cmp` as well?